# SQL replication to SQL Compact 3.5 via FTP?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, replication, merge-replication

I'm trying replicate a SQL Server database to a device with SQL Compact 3.5 on it and I can get replication working fine via IIS. However, the publication has an option to use FTP to publish the replication data, but I don't seem to be able to configure SQL Compact to connect to the FTP site. There's nothing online that says I can't do that, but I also can't find a walk-through showing that I can.

Does anybody know if I can connect a SQL Compact database to a publisher via FTP rather than IIS Web?

Comment: Maybe with snapshot replication http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172918.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is: That's the kind of ambiguous documentation I'm talking about. It's clear that you can use it for snapshot, and there's nothing I can find that says I can't use it for merge, but no instructions or statements that I can use it for merge. For now, I'm going with IIS and just assuming FTP won't work for merge replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported with SQL Server Compact, only IIS based Sync works.

Comment: Just to back this up, the documentation for configuring replication for SQL Server CE does not mention anything other than IIS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152568.aspx

Comment: @ta.speot.is I figured this was the case, though I expected something that said "FTP-based sync doesn't work". I'll accept that it has to be IIS-based. Thanks!